# WSL - Launch bash from Powershell in new terminal and pass a command to it

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to make a simple Powershell script to quickly setup my dev environment. For that I need a few instances of WSL programs running on bash terminals.

From Powershell, I am trying to:

1. Open a new terminal window
2. Start bash
3. Run a command with bash - In my use case I just want to run a simple `npm start` within bash.

A plus is if I can do all of this in one script line.

I think I am close. If I use `start powershell` I can start a new terminal. That inmediately opens a new PowerShell terminal.

Then, I can pass PowersShell commands to it like so:

```
start powershell{bash}
```

This opens a new terminal window and immediately opens bash.

A way to pass commands to bash in PowerShell is like this:

```
bash -c "npm start"
```

This works well. It opens bash in the same terminal and then runs the command I am passing to it. `npm start` works just as if I was calling it directly from bash. The problem comes when I want to pass the `npm start` to the new terminal. This is what I am trying:

```
start powershell{ bash -c "npm start"; Read-host}
```

This opens the new powershell terminal and it seems to be opening bash. `; Read-host` is added so that the terminal doesn't close immediately. However, instead of running the npm command, it reacts by showing me information about the npm command instead of actually running it.

[image]

Is there a workaround so that I can actually get the command to run in the new terminal window after opening bash?

Comment: Does `start wsl -- npm start` work for you?

Comment: Thanks! It doesn't, it shows me the following:
`Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'start'.
At line:1 char:1
+ start wsl -- npm start
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand`

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with powershell. This error looks like a syntax error. Try `start powershell{wsl -- npm start;Read-Host}`

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot! Please answer the question so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the recommended way to start commands in the WSL environment is to use `wsl.exe` now. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference#wslexe)

Try `start powershell{wsl -- npm start; Read-Host}`